# What is a straight-forward way to loop over a grouped data column, and then the sub-data for that group, from data in a pl/sql cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been searching, but this may just be that I don't know what terms to search for in pl/sql to find this (I'm used to coldfusion).

In coldfusion, I can do this:

- query with a standard group by clause
- then loop over results at the group level
- and then loop over items in the group

It would look like this simple code:

```
<cfquery>select group_name, person_name from table_name group by group_name</cfquery>
<cfoutput group="group_name">
  #group_name#
  <cfoutput>
    - #person_name#
  </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Say I have data like this:

```
**group_name**  **person_name**
group 1         person a
group 1         person b
group 1         person c
group 1         person d
group 2         person e
group 2         person f
group 2         person g
group 3         person h
```

My resulting output would be:

```
group 1
- person a
- person b
- person c
- person d
group 2
- person e
- person f
- person g
group 3
- person h
```

I'd appreciate any straight-forward examples that does this type of output after I've pulled the data into a pl/sql cursor.  My ultimate goal is to send a single email per group listing the people in the group, and also to attach files stored as a blob in the database (one file per person).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  -- query with a standard group by clause
  -- then loop over results at the group level
  FOR c1 IN (select group_name from table_name group by group_name)
  LOOP
    
    -- << do some work with c1.group_name >>
    
    -- and then loop over items in the group
    FOR c2 IN (select person_name from table_name WHERE group_name = c1.group_name)
    LOOP

      -- << do some work with c2.person_name and/or c1.group_name >>

    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This simple approach ended up working for my case.  Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Using Anonymous PL/SQL block -

```
DECLARE
    group_id    person_group.group_id%TYPE;
    persons     person_group%ROWTYPE;
    CURSOR c_groups IS
        SELECT group_id 
        FROM person_group 
        GROUP BY group_id
        ORDER BY 1; 
    CURSOR c_persons(in_group VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT group_id, person_name
        FROM person_group
        WHERE group_id = in_group
        ORDER BY 1;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_groups;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_groups INTO group_id;
        EXIT WHEN c_groups%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(group_id);
        OPEN c_persons(group_id);
        LOOP
            FETCH c_persons INTO persons;
            EXIT WHEN c_persons%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  - '||persons.person_name);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_persons;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_groups;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('['||SQLERRM||']');
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I haven't been able to get this functioning for my particular work case (entirely my fault - not a lot of pl/sql experience).